# podman CLI always defaults to local instead of the default remote connection

Tags: podman

I've followed the instructions for connecting to a remote podman service via SSH/sockets to the letter, and I can successfully use it so long as I include either the `--remote` or `--connection` flag on the command line. But when I omit the flag, it always acts on local containers regardless of the default. For example:

This shows that the remote connection is indeed set as the default:

```
$ podman system connection list
Name        URI                                Identity                 Default
podman      ssh://alvin@...podman/podman.sock  /home/alvin/.ssh/id_rsa  true
```

Running with the `--remote` or `--connection` flag correctly executes the command on the server. The listed containers are on the server:

```
$ podman --remote ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                               COMMAND          ...
f88689da46ef  docker.io/neochrome/bastion:latest  /bin/sh -c /start...

$ podman --connection podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                               COMMAND          ...
f88689da46ef  docker.io/neochrome/bastion:latest  /bin/sh -c /start...
```

Omitting the flag always works locally, regardless of the default. **This is showing and acting on local containers!**

```
$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                    COMMAND          ...
f88689da46ef  localhost/broker:latest  /usr/sbin/mosquit...
```

According to countless instructions I've found (they all go through more or less the same steps), this should just work without the extra arguments. I need to use other scripts/services that rely on this working (like podman-compose), and they don't work correctly because of this.

I've tested on multiple systems, including clean installs. All are running variations of RHEL 8 or 9. Thanks!